# json data staying after changing son address. iOS, Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parsing, caching

I am getting json data and parsing it, but for some reason when I change the address to different json and recall the function, (Im changing one eliment in album search), I get the same data in the json. I am thinking it is cached.

Here is my Address:

```
var SEARCH_RESULTS_ADDRESS = "\(BASE_URL)\(choiceSearch!).search&\(choiceSearch!)=\(albumSearch)&api_key=\(API_KEY)&format=json"
```

Here is my AddressDataService function.

```
func getAlbumData(completion: @escaping (_ finished: Bool) -> ()) {
    guard let url = URL(string: SEARCH_RESULTS_ADDRESS) else { return }

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in

        guard let data = data else { return }
        do {

            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let albumDataFull = try decoder.decode(Root.self, from: data)
            albumInfo = []
            for business in albumDataFull.results.albummatches.album {
                let artist = business.artist!
                let name = business.name!
                let imgUrl = business.image

                let albumInd = ["name":name, "artist":artist, "url":url, "imgUrl":imgUrl] as [String : Any]

                albumInfo.append(albumInd)
                print("Tony: \(albumInfo.count)")

            }

            completion(true)
        }catch let jsonErr {
            print("Error seroalizing json", jsonErr)
        }
        }.resume()
}
```

Here is my relead data and address change.

```
func getData(completion: @escaping (_ finished: Bool) -> ()) {
    AlbumDataService().getAlbumData(completion: { (complete) in
        completion(true)

    })
}

func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    albumSearch = searchBar.text
    albumInfo = []
    getData(completion: { (complete) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            SEARCH_RESULTS_ADDRESS = "\(BASE_URL)\(choiceSearch!).search&\(choiceSearch!)=\(albumSearch!)&api_key=\(API_KEY)&format=json"
            print(SEARCH_RESULTS_ADDRESS)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            print("Tony Finishedediting \(albumSearch!)")
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: If you mean you get the same result with two different `SEARCH_RESULTS_ADDRESS`, it would be a problem of your server side.

Comment: I can paste the addresses into webpage and see the different results from them but when I try to parse the different addresses, one shows the result then I change it and call the function again but it shows the same results as if it didn’t clear the last ones

Comment: So, have you checked your server side code? And how have you done _try to parse the different addresses_ ? What's your server log showing?

Comment: I para the firs Jaime fine and display this in a table view, I then change the address (or the album name part) via search bar. When enter is pressed it runs the above function again to parse the new data. The address prints out with the changes in a print statement but the data doesn’t. When add a break point in and hover my curser over the results car it’s the same before and after the search with the same Json data.

Comment: You code shown above has not `print`s showing _address_. Please show your exact code you use.

Comment: I have updated my OP with the code that is relevent, Thank you for your time on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `SEARCH_RESULTS_ADDRESS` **before** it is used.

```
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    albumSearch = searchBar.text
    albumInfo = []
    //###
    SEARCH_RESULTS_ADDRESS = "\(BASE_URL)\(choiceSearch!).search&\(choiceSearch!)=\(albumSearch!)&api_key=\(API_KEY)&format=json"
    print(SEARCH_RESULTS_ADDRESS)
    getData(completion: { (complete) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            print("Tony Finishedediting \(albumSearch!)")
        }
    })
}
```

(Better make it a parameter than declaring a constant-like property.)

---

(ADDITION)

#### how I would make the address a param?

Assuming you can modify the methods of `AddressDataService`:

```
func getAlbumData(_ urlString: String, completion: @escaping (_ finished: Bool) -> ()) {
    print(urlString)
    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
        print("ursString is invalid")
        return
    }

    //...
}
```

And you can use it as:

```
func getData(_ urlString: String, completion: @escaping (_ finished: Bool) -> ()) {
    AlbumDataService().getAlbumData(urlString)  { complete in
        completion(true)
    }
}

func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    albumSearch = searchBar.text
    albumInfo = []
    let searchResultsAddress = "\(BASE_URL)\(choiceSearch!).search&\(choiceSearch!)=\(albumSearch!)&api_key=\(API_KEY)&format=json"
    getData(searchResultsAddress) { complete in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            print("Tony Finishedediting \(albumSearch!)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course, makes sense, how I missed that i dont know. again thank you for your time on this, this solved the issue. I am not sure how I would make the address a param?

Comment: @TonyMerritt, Added an example.